# Issue with nested loop

Tags: perl

I got file called numbers.txt which is basically line with 5 numbers:
they look like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

What I'm trying to achieve is I want to read those numbers from the line (which already works), then in each iteration I want to add +1 to every number which was read from that file and print them on screen with print, so the final result should look like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
```

.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open("handle", 'numbers.txt') or die('unable to open numbers file\n');
$/ = ' ';

OUT: for my $line (<handle>) {
        for (my $a = 0; $a < 5; $a++) {
            chomp $line;
            $line += 1;
            print "$line ";
                next OUT;
        }
}
close("handle");
```

Haven't done looping in perl for a while now and would be great if someone could provide working example.

Also, it would be great if you could provide more than one working example, just to be future proof ;)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this on for size.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open("handle", 'numbers.txt') or die('unable to open numbers file\n');

for my $line (<handle>) {
    chomp $line;
    for my $number (split /\s+/, $line) {
        for (my $a = $number; $a < $number+5; $a++) {
            print "$a ";
        }       
        print "\n";
    }
}
close("handle");
```

You can dispense with **$/=' '** and instead let the outer loop iterate on lines of the file.
For each line you want to iterate for each number which is separated by white space, thus the **split /\s+/, $line** which gives you a list of numbers for the inner loop.
For your output $a starts at the number read from the file.

Comment: `split /\s+/` should almost always be `split ' '`

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you're after:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
    my @split = split;
    my $count = 0;
    for (1..4){
        $count++;
        foreach (@split){ 
            my $num = $_ + $count;
            print "$num ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }

}

__DATA__
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**   Added another method, this one in line with the posted approach.

---

Increment each number in the string, changing the string in place. Repeat that. Below are two ways to do that. Yet another method reads individual numbers and prints following integer sequences.

(1)  With regular expressions.  It also fits in one-liner

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | perl -e '$v = <>; for (1..5) { print $v; $v =~ s/(\d+)/$1+1/eg; }'
```

This prints the desired output.  But better put it in a script

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'numbers.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "can't open $file: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {  
    # Add chomp($line) if needed for some other processing.
    for (1..5) {
        print $line;
        $line =~ s/(\d+)/$1+1/eg;
    }   
}
```

The `/e` modifier is crucial for this. It makes the replacement side of the regex be evaluated as code instead of as a double-quoted string. So you can actually execute code there and here we add to the captured number, `$1+1`, for each matched number as `/g` moves down the string. This changes the string so the next iteration of the `for (1..5)` increments those, etc. I match multiple digits, `\d+`, which isn't necessary in your example but makes far more sense in general.

(2) Via [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) + [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) + [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html), also repeatedly changing the line in place

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    for (1..5) {
        print $line;
        $line = join ' ', map { $_+1 } split '\s+', $line;            
    }
}
```

The `split` gets the list of numbers from `$line` and feeds it to `map`, which increments each, feeding its output list to `join`. The joined string is assigned back to `$line`, and this is repeated.  I split by `\s+` to allow multiple white space but this makes it very 'relaxed' in what input format it accepts, see [`perlrecharclass`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Whitespace). If you know it's one space please change that to `' '`.

(3) Take a number at a time and print the integer sequence starting from it.

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "can't open $file: $!";
local $/ = ' ';
while (my $num = <$fh>) {
    print "$_ " for $num..$num+4; 
    print "\n";
}
```

The magical `4` can be coded by pre-processing the whole line to find the sequence length, say by

```
my $len = () = $line =~ /(\d+)/g;
```

or by `split`-ing into an array and taking its `scalar`, then using `$len-1`.

---

Additional comments.

- I recommend the three-argument open, `open my $fh, '<', $file`
- When you check a call print the error, `die "Your message: $!"`, to see  the reason for failure. If *you* decide to quit, `if ($bad) { die "Got $bad" }`, then you may not need `$!`. But when an external call fails you *don't know* the reason so you need the suitable error variable, most often `$!`.

Comment: @jonasv Updated: added another method (more like OP), fixed a blooper in regex, changed prints around to streamline.

Answer (score 1):

Here no need to use nested loop it's always program make slower.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @num = split(" ",(<DATA>)[0]);  

foreach my $inc (0..$#num)
{
    print map{$inc+$_," "}@num;  # Add one by one in array element
    print "\n";
}


__DATA__
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a number of problems. Here is what's stopping it working

- You are setting the record separator to a single space. Your input file contains `"1 2 3 4 5\n"`, so the `while` loop will iterate five times setting `$line` to `"1 "`, `"2 "`, `"3 "`, `"4 "`, `"5\n"`
- Your `for` loop is set up to iterate five times. It does `chomp $line` which removes the space after the number, then increments `$line` and prints it. Then you jump out of the `for` loop, having executed it only once, with `next OUT`. This results in each value in the file being incremented by one and printed, so you get `2 3 4 5 6`
- Removing the unnecessary `next OUT`, produces something closer

  ```
  2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9 10
  ```

  There are now five numbers being printed for each number in the input file
- Adding `print "\n"` after the `for` loop help separate the lines

  ```
  2 3 4 5 6 
  3 4 5 6 7 
  4 5 6 7 8 
  5 6 7 8 9 
  6 7 8 9 10
  ```
- Now we need to print the number *before* it is incremented instead of *afterwards*. If we swap `$line += 1` and `print "$line "` we get this

  ```
  1 2 3 4 5 
  2 3 4 5 6 
  3 4 5 6 7 
  4 5 6 7 8 
  5
   6 7 8 9
  ```

  What is happening here is that the `5` is still followed be a newline, which now appears in the output. The `chomp` won't remove this because it removes the value of `$/` from the end of a string. You've set that to a space, so it will remove only spaces. The fix is to replace `chomp` with a substitution `s/\s+//g` which removes *all whitespace from the string. You also need to do that only once so I've put it outside the `for` loop at the top

Now we get this

```
    1 2 3 4 5 
    2 3 4 5 6 
    3 4 5 6 7 
    4 5 6 7 8 
    5 6 7 8 9
```

And this is your code as it ended up

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open( "handle", 'numbers.txt' ) or die('unable to open numbers file\n');

$/ = ' ';

for my $line (<handle>) {

    $line =~ s/\s+//g;

    for ( my $a = 0; $a < 5; $a++ ) {
        print "$line ";
        $line += 1;
    }

    print "\n";
}

close("handle");
```

There are a few other best practices that could improve your program

- Use `use warnings 'all'`
- Use lexical file handles, and the three-parameter form of `open`
- Use `local` if you are changing Perl's built-in variables
- Put `$!` into your `die` string so that you know *why* the `open` failed
- Avoid the C-style `for` loop, and iterate over a list instead

Making these fixes as well looks like this. The output is identical to the above

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $fh, '<', 'numbers.txt'
        or die qq{Unable to open "numbers.txt" for input: $!};

local $/ = ' ';

for my $line ( <$fh> ) {

    $line =~ s/\s+//g;

    for my $a ( 0 .. 4 ) {
        print "$line ";
        ++$line;
    }

    print "\n";
}
```